# JQuery ".closest()" equivalent in HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack`. Does it have a function similar to `jQuery` `closest`? (closest parent that matches a CSS selector). I tried google and the website http://html-agility-pack.net - and both don't appear to have an answer.

Comment: You can check a below sample to match the class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no built-in method currently, you can write a `Extension method` to achieve this.

I have written a simple extension method which can be used to find elements with `tagName`, `ID` and `class` names that you can use.

Anyways it can be further extended easily to match other selectors.

```
public static class HtmlAgilityPackExtensions
{
    public static HtmlNode Closest(this HtmlNode node, string jQuerySelector)
    {
        if (node == null) return null;
        string tagName = "", id = "";
        var classes = new List<string>();

        if (jQuerySelector.Contains("."))
        {
            var parts = jQuerySelector.Split('.');

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parts[0]))
            {
                tagName = parts[0];
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < parts.Length; i++)
            {
                classes.Add(parts[i]);
            }
        }

        if (jQuerySelector.Contains("#"))
        {
            var parts = jQuerySelector.Split('#');

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parts[0]))
            {
                tagName = parts[0];
            }

            id = parts[1];
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tagName) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id) && classes.Count == 0)
        {
           tagName = jQuerySelector;
        }

        HtmlNode closestParent = null;

        while (node.ParentNode != null && closestParent == null)
        {
            var isClosest = true;
            node = node.ParentNode;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tagName))
            {
                isClosest = node.Name == tagName;
            }

            if (isClosest && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
            {
                isClosest = node.Id == id;
            }

            if (isClosest && classes.Count > 0)
            {
                var classNames = node.GetAttributeValue("class", "");
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(classNames))
                {
                    foreach (string c in classes)
                    {
                        isClosest = classNames.Contains(c);
                        if (!isClosest) break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isClosest)
            {
                closestParent = node;
            }
        }

        return closestParent;
    }
}
```

**Test Code**

```
       var html = "<div><div id='parent1' class='parent'><span id='parent2' class='parent'><div id='parent3' class='parent'><div id='TestNode' class='child'>Test node</div></div></span></div></div>";
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        var testNode1 = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='TestNode']");
        if (testNode1 != null)
        {
            var parent1 = testNode1.Closest(".parent");
            var parent2 = testNode1.Closest("#parent1");
            var parent3 = testNode1.Closest("span.parent");
            var nonExistingParent = testNode1.Closest("span.parent1");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same thing, but couldn't find any, so I wrote my own `Closest` function:

```
public static HtmlNode Closest(this HtmlNode node, string search)
{
    search = search.ToLower();
    while (node.ParentNode != null)
    {
        if (node.ParentNode.Name.ToLower() == search) return node.ParentNode;
        node = node.ParentNode;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This one only works for tag names (as I needed) you can extend it to classes, attributes, and ...